# Rails & Youtube: Can I get notified when a new video is uploaded by a specific channel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube, webhooks

I am looking for some sort of webhook that notifies my app when a new video is uploaded by a channel, so that I can create a new Video object in my app.

The only resource I could find was [youtube push notifications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications), but not sure if this is what I'm looking for or how to implement it in a rails app.

Could I get a brief overview on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have found your answer. I'd recommend working through the Youtube Api and push notifications docs starting with the page you found, then looking at the PubSubHubbub github docs since that is the solution google has implemented for you. In the process you will probably become much more adept at working with the youtube data API.

Alternately you could use a scheduling gem to periodically check the list(s) yourself but I believe this might end up being more work for a worse solution.